# Grid View Summary / Detail (Tabs?)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, reporting, tabs

I have a very specific problem with a Gridview I am displaying.

Believe it or not my customers need to see roughly 30 columns for a particular report.

Obviously displaying these legibly is impossible and I am looking for suggestions on how to achieve this neatly?

I was thinking Ajax tabs groups columns together naturally on differing tabs.

My main worry is that Gridview "date range" is created dynamically depending upon the values in 2 calendar controls. Would this work i.e could I reference the external controls across these tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your GridView in a Panel control with both scrollbars display set to true.

This way the page will fit properly without scrolls but only the GridView will have the scroll-bars. and your users can scroll horizontally or vertically to go through the report.